# Can not login to mysql 5.7.9 after change password

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have installed Mysql **Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.9, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper** On **CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503**

I Changed root password using this command:

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'XXXXXXX';  
flush privileges;
```

After re-login

```
[root@server ~]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

> ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin
>   '*A6074285732753D325C55AD74E7517CF442C1A81' is not loaded

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two things have changed since earlier versions of mySQL (I''m using 5.7.10):

1. `systemd` is now used to look after mySQL instead of `mysqld_safe` (which is why I was getting the `-bash: mysqld_safe: command not found` error - it's not installed)
2. The `user` table structure has changed.

So to reset the root password, you still start mySQL with `--skip-grant-tables` options and update the `user` table, but how you do it has changed.

```
1. Stop mysql:
systemctl stop mysqld

2. Set the mySQL environment option 
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"

3. Start mysql usig the options you just set
systemctl start mysqld

4. Login as root
mysql -u root

5. Update the root user password with these mysql commands
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword')
    -> WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit

6. Stop mysql
systemctl stop mysqld

7. Unset the mySQL envitroment option so it starts normally next time
systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS

8. Start mysql normally:
systemctl start mysqld

Try to login using your new password:
7. mysql -u root -p
```

---

**Reference**

As it says at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html,

> **Note**
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.6, for MySQL installation using an RPM
>   distribution, server startup and shutdown is managed by systemd on
>   several Linux platforms. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is no longer
>   installed because it is unnecessary. For more information, see Section
>   2.5.10, “Managing MySQL Server with systemd”.

Which takes you to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html where it mentions the `systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS=` towards the bottom of the page.

The password reset commands are at the bottom of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: After using your instruction for resetting MySQL root password, I got `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.` after executing every command in MySQL prompt, even after `ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED BY 'MY_NEW_PASSWORD';` I did a search and then found the solution here `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html`.  You need to run `ALTER USER USER() IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';` in MySQL console.

Answer (score 1):

You should use update on mysql user table when changing any user, especially root.

You should follow these steps to reset it:

```
How to reset the root password for mysql:
Stop mysql:
1. service mysql stop

Run mysql with skip grants to be able to login without any password
2. mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

Login as root
3. mysql -u root

4. mysql commands:
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("YourPWHere") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit

Stop mysql
5. service mysql stop

Start mysql normally:
6. service mysql start

Try to login using your new password:
7. mysql -u root -p
```

Update:

Apparently this method will not work for 5.7, please refer to [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) and [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html) instead.

Comment: The problem is "As of MySQL 5.7.6, for MySQL installation using an RPM distribution, server startup and shutdown is managed by systemd on several Linux platforms. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is no longer installed because it is unnecessary. For more information, see Section 2.5.10, “Managing MySQL Server with systemd”."

Comment: As I said I'm using Mysql 5.7.9 on Centos 7.1 and mysqld_safe command DOES'NT exists !

Comment: read what it says at the end of the link above...`Because mysqld_safe is not installed when systemd is used, options previously specified for that program (for example, in an [mysqld_safe] option group) must be specified another way`....I have not really done anything with 5.7 and we have not moved to CentOS 7, CASE IN POINT HERE...

Comment: and what other way is this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Steps to reset the password.

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Reset the MySql server root password.

```
$sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

**Output Something like-:**

```
     10.744785Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: o!5y,oJGALQa
```

Use the above password during reset mysql_secure_installation process.

```
   $ sudo mysql_secure_installation
       Securing the MySQL server deployment.

       Enter password for user root:
```

You have successfully reset the root password of MySql Server.
Use the below command to check the mysql server connecting or not.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

See my article: [Install Latest MySQL 5.7 on RHEL/Centos 7](http://gotechnies.com/install-latest-mysql-5-7-rhelcentos-7/)