# How to change the MySQL root account password on CentOS 7?

Tags: mysql, centos

I have installed mySQL on a CentOS 7 VM but I have problems logging in with root.

I tried logging in without password or tried any default ones (like `mysql`, `admin` etc) I looked in the `my.cnf` file and there's no password. I tried changing the password by stopping the service and restarting it with:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

But I get this message:

```
mysqld_safe:command not found
```

I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: You'll need to specify the full path to the command. If you don't know what that is, `find` is your friend. The password will not be, *should not be* expressed in `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

What version of mySQL are you using? I''m using 5.7.10 and had the same problem with logging on as root

There is 2 issues - why can't I log in as root to start with, and why can I not use 'mysqld_safe` to start mySQL to reset the root password.

I have no answer to setting up the root password during installation, but here's what you do to reset the root password

**Edit**: the initial root password on install can be found by running

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

---

1. `systemd` is now used to look after mySQL instead of `mysqld_safe` (which is why you get the `-bash: mysqld_safe: command not found` error - it's not installed)
2. The `user` table structure has changed.

So to reset the root password, you still start mySQL with `--skip-grant-tables` options and update the `user` table, but how you do it has changed.

1. Stop MySQL:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mysqld
   ```
2. Set the MySQL environment option:

   ```
   sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
   ```
3. Start MySQL using the options you just set:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mysqld
   ```
4. Login as root

   ```
   mysql -u root
   ```
5. Update the root user password with these mysql commands:

   ```
   mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword')
       -> WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   mysql> quit
   ```

   **Edit**: As mentioned my shokulei in the comments, for 5.7.6 and later, you should use:

   ```
   mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
   ```

   Or you'll get a warning
6. Stop MySQL

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mysqld
   ```
7. Unset the MySQL environment option so it starts normally next time:

   ```
   sudo systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
   ```
8. Start MySQL normally:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mysqld
   ```
9. Try to login using your new password:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

---

**Reference**

As it says at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html,

> **Note**
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.6, for MySQL installation using an RPM
> distribution, server startup and shutdown is managed by systemd on
> several Linux platforms. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is no longer
> installed because it is unnecessary. For more information, see Section
> 2.5.10, “Managing MySQL Server with systemd”.

Which takes you to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html where it mentions the `systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS=` towards the bottom of the page.

The password reset commands are at the bottom of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I realise that this is pretty much the same answer as I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374314/can-not-login-to-mysql-5-7-9-after-change-password/34207145#34207145 but I'm not sure of what I should do if it's essentially the same answer to 2 questions - give 2 answers or link from one to the other?

Comment: This was an excellent answer where there really was no unified source for a single answer in this exact situation.  If only I had found this sooner, it would have saved a few hours of work.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks!grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: Finally, I found clear working instructions. Everywhere mentioned mysqld_safe command, but it is not found on my RedHat.

Comment: Thank you!  I am using MySQL 5.7.18.  I have to use [ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';] instead of the [update user..] query.

Comment: It's worth noting that at least as of time of writing this also works with MariaDB. Just replace `mysqld` with `mariadb.service` and it works exactly the same - the options are identical.

Comment: Thanks a ton,I was struggling from 2-3 hours & no one on stackoverflow mentioned clear steps.

Comment: MySQL recommends `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` for sql < 5.7.5 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html also for 5.6 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Best solution so far.

Comment: Thanks. I found the required password with that way. Now, I can reset it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should give @KevinJones a medal! Took me like an hour to get this working in CentOs!

Comment: @Kevin Jones 'mysql -u root' gives me an error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: In step 5, I had to change "authentication_string" by "Password". Otherwise, it wouldn't let me to log in. MySQL 5.6.46.

Comment: This didn't work just now (2-Aug-2020) for CentOS 7 and MySQL CE v8.0.32-1.el7. Neither of the alternatives for step 5 ("UPDATE ..." or "ALTER USER...") worked. Sadly, I'm now unable to get systemctl to start WITHOUT the "--skip-grant-tables" option.

At this point the easiest way forward is to delete and rebuild the VM.

Comment: As Tom says, none of these instructions work. The moment I remove `skip-grant-tables` it again says "`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`". I am using MariaDB version: `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB`, which is what YUM installs on CentOS 8.

Comment: @PKHunter, Tom  - This is specifically for MySQL 5.7.10  on Centos 7. I wouldn't have thought that Centos 8  would make much different, but the security (passwords, etc) is different on MySQL 8, so that will be the problem. Sorry,

Answer (score 28):

I used the advice of Kevin Jones above with the following --skip-networking change for slightly better security:

```
sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking"

[user@machine ~]$ mysql -u root
```

Then when attempting to reset the password I received an error, but googling elsewhere suggested I could simply forge ahead.  The following worked:

```
mysql> select user(), current_user();
+--------+-----------------------------------+
| user() | current_user()                    |
+--------+-----------------------------------+
| root@  | skip-grants user@skip-grants host |
+--------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sup3rPw#'
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sup3rPw#'
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
[user@machine ~]$ systemctl stop mysqld
[user@machine ~]$ sudo systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
[user@machine ~]$ systemctl start mysqld
```

At that point I was able to log in.

Comment: @user48918  'mysql -u root' gives me an error   "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Answer (score 13):

Use the below Steps to reset the password.

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Reset the MySql server root password.

```
$sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Output Something like-:

```
 10.744785Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: o!5y,oJGALQa
```

Use the above password during reset mysql_secure_installation process.

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

You have successfully reset the root password of MySql Server. Use the below command to check the mysql server connecting or not.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

http://gotechnies.com/install-latest-mysql-5-7-rhelcentos-7/

Comment: As far as I can understand, this only works when the server is first created.  All that grep command does is find the temporary password, not set it.

Answer (score 11):

For **CentOS 7** and **MariaDB 10.4**, I had success with the following commands:

```
su -
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables --user=mysql"
systemctl restart mariadb
mysql -u root

flush privileges;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
flush privileges;
quit

systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
systemctl restart mariadb
```

Comment: Worked as well !

Comment: this worked for me, i dont get why centos has to give you crap just to start MySQL or MariaDB, I went through a lot for me to get here !

Comment: Doesn't work. Even after all this, when I remove the MYSQLD_OPTS, and enter the right password, the command line says `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. Using the latest version - `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB`.

Comment: @PKHunter Feel free to upload a video of your steps. I'll then tell you where the issue is and how to solve it. Also, keep in mind that these instructions habe been posted for MariaDB `10.4`. The version you posted says `10.3`. So theses steps don't apply to your version.

Comment: Also, you'd need to add `use mysql` to the commands after the first flush privileges.

Comment: @PKHunter In addition to you using MariaDB `10.3`, your comments on other answers reveal that you are also using CentOS 8, which is clearly not CentOS 7 for which this answers has been written. (Just FYI, I flagged most (not all) of your comments on the various answer to this question for various reasons, to be reviewed and potentially removed. For further information, read the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). In my personal experience, it is usually a good idea to ensure enough blood sugar and give it a couple of hours, before writing questionable comments.)

Comment: Thank you. I did ask it, and a mod closed my question pointing me to this one. Anyway, I've raised it again. Yes, it's CentOS and Mariadb 10.5 based on their own repo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552235/mariadb-latest-10-5-version-cannot-change-root-password-and-it-doesnt-work-wit -- thank you for your help.

Comment: @PKHunter Thanks for your understanding. I'll take a look at your new question, but it might take an hour or two, because I probably have to setup a VM with CentOS 8 first.

Answer (score 9):

Here a little bit twist with `mysql-community-server` 5.7.

I share some steps, how to reset MySQL 5.7 root password or set password. it will work CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 as well.

1. Stop your MySQL:

   ```
   service mysqld stop
   ```
2. Modify `/etc/my.cnf` file add `skip-grant-tables`:

   ```
   vi /etc/my.cnf
   [mysqld]
   skip-grant-tables
   ```
3. Start MySQL:

   ```
   service mysqld start
   ```
4. Select MySQL default database

   ```
   mysql -u root

   mysql>use mysql;
   ```
5. Set a new password

   ```
   update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("yourpassword") where User='root';
   ```
6. Remove `skip-grant-tables` from `/etc/my.cnf` file.
7. Restart MySQL:

   ```
   service mysqld restart

   mysql -u root -p
   ```

Comment: Please be clear that after it's done, the `skip-grant-tables` should be removed from my.cnf. It's insecure as it doesn't require password. This is not very sound advice.

Answer (score 2):

Please stop all services MySQL with following command:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

After it use this:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

It may work properly.

Answer (score 1):

For me work like this:
1. Stop mysql:
systemctl stop mysqld

2. Set the mySQL environment option 
   systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
3. Start mysql usig the options you just set
   systemctl start mysqld
4. Login as root
   mysql -u root
5. After login I use FLUSH PRIVILEGES; tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work.
   If i don't do that i receive this error trying to update the password:
   "Can't find any matching row in the user table"