# SQL Reset root password

Tags: mysql

Im trying to reset the root password for MySQL, on centos7. I was following a guide where I use

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root';
```

That gives me a big ol syntax error tho

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('new-password') WHERE User='root'' at line 1

Comment: Which version of MySQL

Comment: [reset root pemissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). Adjust URL to major version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change mysql root password on Centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510184/change-mysql-root-password-on-centos7)