# MariaDB latest 10.5 version cannot change root password, and it doesn't work without skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have tried everything mentioned here:
[How to change the MySQL root account password on CentOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510184/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-account-password-on-centos7)

It does NOT answer the question. None of those suggestions work. (To mods: please don't close this question because it's beyond that other post, and no one is answering comments there.)

1. With mariadb freshly installed on CentOS 8, using mariadb's own recommended repo, the version installed is: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib **10.5.8-MariaDB**. This somehow creates some root password because running `mysql_secure_installation` one cannot just use an empty password. Using the grep temporary password suggested in that other question yields nothing. There's nothing in the mariadb install log found at `/usr/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`.
2. With `skip-grant-tables` on, either via env or via the my.cnf file, the password for root seems to work. Flush privileges, quit. Everything seems to be fine. It seems to have worked. But then when skip-grant-tables is disabled (as it should be for security), the password does NOT work again.

   ## mysql -u root

   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

   ## mysql -u root -p

   Enter password:
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have stopped the server, yum removed mariadb, then yum installed it again. Same issue. Any ideas on what I am missing? Why is this so complex?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you just want to change the password for the MariaDB `root` database user to some custom (non-empty) password of your choice, using CentOS 8 and MariaDB 10.5.8, correct?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, this is just for security. And I want to be able to use my own command prompt `mysql` without having `skip-grant-tables` enabled at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [Install MariaDB Server 10.5 on CentOS 8](https://www.centlinux.com/2020/05/install-mariadb-server-105-on-centos-8.html) guide, to successfully install and setup a MariaDB 10.5.8 instance and change its `root` password without any issues on a vanilla CentOS 8 installation.

I ran the following commands (in addition to the MariaDB repository setup) as root/superuser:

```
dnf update -y
dnf install -y MariaDB-server
systemctl enable --now mariadb.service
systemctl status mariadb.service
mariadb -u root
```

Then, in the MariaDB console, I ran the following:

```sql
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'MyRootUserPassword';
alter user 'mysql'@'localhost' identified by 'MyMysqlUserPassword';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Afterwards, back on the command line, this time as a regular user, I am able to also login as the database root:

```
mariadb -u root -pMyRootUserPassword
```

---

There is no `skip-grant-tables` needed at all for a vanilla installation of MariaDB.

If you already played around with it before, but you don't care about the previous installation, make sure to completely uninstall MariaDB first and to remove the old data files and `my.cnf` file, so that old configuration, permissions and database users are not kept and later reused when reinstalling MariaDB.

The default data directory for MariaDB 10.5 on CentOS 8 is `/var/lib/mysql`, unless the path has been overwritten in the `/etc/my.cnf` file.

So after uninstalling MariaDb with your package manager of choice, remove/move/rename the directory to ensure that your new MariaDB installation will get a clean slate.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose in my uninstalling (yum remove) I did not also "remove old data files". Where are those files? Right now mariadb does *not* work with the password as it doesn't recognize my password, and it also doesn't work without password because some password is apparently set. Where can I find out? I have multiple databases live right now, so it's painful to remove everything but I have to, I will -- which "data files" to remove, from where, after doing a `yum remove`? Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. So, basically:
1. `yum remove mariadb-server mariadb`
2. Delete completely the `/var/lib/mysql` directory 
3. Delete the `/etc/my.cnf` file 

Anything else?

Comment: That should be all.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Great progress! Now the server is running and the root user is fine, but the Wordpress doesn't work. Says "Error establishing a database connection". But the database can be seen in the `show databases` list!

Comment: I try this command: `mysql -u WPUSER -h localhost -p`  (and enter the right password for this user on a WP database), and the error message I now get, for the first time, `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'WPUSER'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Make sure that the user configured in the `wp-config.php` file does actually exist in your MariaDB instance and that it has access to the configured database (that of course also need to exist).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226785/discussion-between-pkhunter-and-lauxjpn).

Comment: This answer says that you don't need to do the `skip-grant-tables` thing with MariaDB. I've found conflicting instructions on random website for changing the root user password, but haven't been able to find an explanation of when `skip-grant-tables` is needed (or not needed) and why.

Comment: @Scribblemacher The internet is wide and full of incorrect information on random websites. I don't remember anymore if I looked into why `skip-grant-tables` is is not needed for MariaDB 10.5 on CentOS 8, just that theses instructions work for that environment. Since CentOS is being discontinued, it might not be worth it to go down the rabbit hole to find out.