# Can't access user 'root' password in newly installed mySQL80 in Centos7

Tags: mysql, server, centos7

I was recently assigned to administer our own webserver hosted locally. And I accidentally deleted some files in my mysql folder using an FTP client that causes to can't access the myphpadmin or can access mySQL. OS use s CEntos7 and previous mySQL is version 5 something. To no avail in accessing and cant find solution I resorted to removing the sql instance and installing a fresh copy of mySQL80 community release.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374314/can-not-login-to-mysql-5-7-9-after-change-password/34207145#34207145) solution but still to no avail. Yes, I've changed the password and still cant login even I view the root@localhost authentication_string to see to it if the string was change to new password.

Is there any other way to resolve this problem? I'm planning to remove the mysql instance and reinstall it again. Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: "Is there any other way to resolve this problem?" -- Restore from a backup.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best move. Unfortunately, I don't have backup to restore. That's my bad. Is it recommendable to have the same username and password with your centos and mysql?

Comment: How did you set the password? Many people make a mistake there and double-encrypt it by accident.

Comment: **DO NOT** use the actual `root` password in your database. Keep these different. Your actual `root` user should not have a (known) password, just set it to a 64-letter random string. You should be using `sudo` for access to that facility.

Comment: I reinstalled phpmyadmin and mysql80-community-release today. Extracted the temporary password and successfully change the temporary password to new one. But still I  received the Error 1045 (2800): Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)